# android: How to ListView with existing array

Tags: android, arrays, listview

I want a ListView to display some Text on the Screen. I try somethnig like that:

```
Standings[] addressArray = new Standings[18];
...
Arrays.sort(addressArray, StandingsSort.ORDER_BY_RULES);   
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addressArray);
```

But eclipse tell me:

> The constructor ArrayAdapter(StandingsActivity, int,
>   Standings[]) is undefined

How can I fix it?

Comment: the type of your array and the type of `ArrayAdapter` have to be the same

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code It will works.

```
           ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.list, addressArray);
```

Comment: i don't think so, because his array is of type `Standings` and his (and your) ArrayAdapter of type `String`

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand that Standings are what type object, but you should use String array with this:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addressArray);
```

or try like this:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Standings>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, addressArray);
```